# Python: Cursor 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am trying to play around with this simple sql query using cursor:

```
import jaydebeapi,pandas as pd

conn = <connection to TeraData>
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = ("Select top 10 * from Car_Sales")
data = cursor.execute(sql)
print(data.query)
row = data.fetchone()
#rows = data.fetchall()
print(row)
```

Error I am getting is:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'

It has been couple hours trying to find the issue but not getting anywhere on this. Looked different resources online but still the issue remains.

Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Update:

When I executed the same query in Pandas:

```
pd.read_sql_query('select top 10 * from  Car_Sales',conn)
```

Output:

```
Car_Sales
0 112
1 77
2 226
3 990
4 552
5 887
```

Comment: This means that `data` is None. Maybe your SQL query is invalid? "Select top 10 * Car_Sales" doesn't look like a correct query to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told us which connection library you're using, but in cases I'm familiar with (`psycopg`, etc) `cursor.execute()` doesn't return a result set. Try issuing the `fetchone` and `fetchall` commands against the `cursor` (rather than `data`):

```
conn = <connection to TeraData>
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Select top 10 * from Car_Sales")

row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)

# rows = cursor.fetchall()   
# print(rows)
```

---

*Update*

A tidbit from Blckknght's comment - take a look at the [Python Database API Spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15): "Return values are not defined" for `cursor.execute`.

Comment: Indeed, this is part of the [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) which most libraries try to follow.

Comment: @chris Apologies I am using Jaydebeapi library. Have updated the question.